# Forward to certain URL

Tags: url, dns, forwarding, forward

What I want to have:

1. User enters 'gmail.com'.
2. A message in the web browser appears stating some like "You are accessing third party email service... and so on..".
3. User will be given option to proceed by clicking certain link
   pointing to 'gmail.com'.

**What I did:** Use DNS forward A record forwarding to internal ip of server where message is stored.

**What happens:** Loop back to internal ip occurs when user clicks provided link when user wants to proceed to 'gmail.com'

Is there any other way possible to do this? other than DNS?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using a proxy server such as squid. You can place a custom app/script to make certain checks on the source/client if he already have been redirected to such a "warning message page". You can for example append the original url to the end of your redirect url so you can easily place a link on the site.
http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Redirectors

Answer (score 0):

You could place code on the DNS server which keeps track of who has been redirected and who's free to go to the link.  It'd need to have some kind of database and store MAC addresses of users who don't need to be redirected.